# Получение нескольких значений из строки

Tags: c#

Есть строка `name;mail;key`. Как отдельно получить каждое значение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте метод [`String.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string s = "name;mail;key";
string[] parts = s.Split(';');
```

В массиве `parts` у вас будут лежать элементы `"name"`, `"mail"` и `"key"`.